# Storybook behavior of array.map() with specific array initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, storybook

**Context**

I have this construct:

```
[...new Array(2)].map((value, index) => `item${index}`)
```

When running it from browser, node, or jest tests, it consistently produces:

```
['item0', 'item1']
```

If I just had the same without the array clone using the spread operator:

```
new Array(2).map((value, index) => `item${index}`)
```

Then I would get (as expected, due to how `map` works):

```
[undefined, undefined]
```

Reasons for the above are explained here (I did not know this before):

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#description]

**Problem**

I had this bug - when using storybook, even when using array clone:

```
[...new Array(2)].map((value, index) => `item${index}`)
```

I get the following result:

```
[undefined, undefined]
```

Fixing the issue is not a problem, I get the proper result when including `.fill()`:

```
[...new Array(2).fill(undefined)].map((value, index) => `item${index}`)
```

But the question is, why would the above work differently with storybook? Does anyone know this?

**Storybook Config**

I am using [Nx Framework](https://nx.dev/) for project creation, and pretty much the default storybook config.

This is the in-project configuration for storybook:

```
const rootMain = require('../../../.storybook/main');

module.exports = {
  ...rootMain,

  core: { ...rootMain.core, builder: 'webpack5' },

  stories: [
    ...rootMain.stories,
    '../src/app/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../src/app/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [...rootMain.addons, '@nrwl/react/plugins/storybook'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // apply any global webpack configs that might have been specified in .storybook/main.js
    if (rootMain.webpackFinal) {
      config = await rootMain.webpackFinal(config, { configType });
    }

    // add your own webpack tweaks if needed

    return config;
  },
};
```

And this is the root storybook configuration referenced at the top of the above code block:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials'],
};
```

Comment: Dunno - is Storybook doing any transformation of the code? Or did it perhaps cache your old code or something?

Comment: Also, for the record it's probably better to do `Array.from({length: 2}, (value, index) => \`item${index}\`)`

Comment: You might be using a transpiler that converts spread syntax and supplies an incomplete polyfill?

Comment: @VLAZ I added a few more details regarding storybook to my post. I am not doing anything special there, just using the default configuration that was created for me by NX, although obviously a lot will happen here under the hood. I don't think there is any caching being done here, if I just paste the example I described in the post into a stories file, and `console.log` it, it will produce the above mentioned result. +1 for the code recommendation, it is a better choice.

Comment: @Bergi Do you have any idea how I might be able to check this?

Comment: @mrzli Look at the transpiled code. And/or put a breakpoint there in your browser, disabling source maps.